# Must every NP-Complete Problem have a class of instances which is solvable in Poly time?

Tags: np-complete, polynomial-time

Is there any theorem that states that any NP-Complete Problem has a class of instances solvable in Poly time? For example, some problems like vertex cover are NP-Complete on general graphs but can be solved in polynomial time on instances which are Trees. Does every NP-Complete problem have such class?

Comment: You mean a subset of problems where a naive backtracking solver will never need to branch out?

Comment: Not only NP-complete, but even unsolvable (in general) problems under some restrictions are solvable in poly-time.

Comment: Will this work: **If the class of instances is finite then they are solvable in $O(1)$**. For example if you create a class of any 10 instances of the Vertex cover then they are solvable in $O(1)$.

Comment: @fade2black, yeah, surely there should be instances that can be solved in $O(1)$ time also. Like SAT where first $O(1)$ clauses form unsatisfiable formula. There are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Also, every NP-complete problem is reducible to 3SAT. If you manage to create a 1-1 reduction from problem instances to a 3SAT then all "special" instances reducible to 2SAT are solvable in polytime.

Comment: As @fade2black points out, every problem is trivial on any finite class of instances. Likewise, every language $L$ is trivial if you restrict to instances within $L$ (e.g., SAT is trivial over any class of satisfiable formulas) or to instances not in $L$ (e.g., SAT over any class of unsatisfiable formulas). So, without further restrictions, the question is trivial.

Comment: The answer to this question is yes, because the BH Isomorphism Conjecture is true. Even if I am too lazy to provide a proper answer, I am against closing this question. Here is a [presentation, which explains the isomorphism thm, its relation to the Schröder-Bernstein thm, and related ideas like the gap thm](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/pub/EricMike60.pdf).